# How to make Firefox auto update Flash Player

Tags: firefox, flash, plugins

I'm not sure if this is a common problem or just mine, I often find Firefox is not playing YouTube videos because Flash player is not being updated automatically like the rest of the plug-ins. I always have to manually update it.

Is it possible to make Firefox auto update this plugin? How did you deal with it?

Comment: Why not disable the flash player entirely and use the Youtube HTML5 video player? Less of the security problems and none of the waiting for the plugin to update... https://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: my firefox is already set that way, but if I dont have flash updatedt he videos wont play, probably no tall videos supports html5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube no longer uses Flash to serve videos on most browsers, rather HTML5's Video feature. Older versions of Firefox however are an exception. You can force Youtube to play their videos via html5 player by adding this to the tail end of your youtube URL:

`&html5=True`

Like:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdnA-ESWcPs&html5=True

To have FireFox update it's Flash player automatically, you'll need to edit your existing Flash update settings. 
Here is a snippet from an article by **Kyle Beckman** over on 4sysops.com:

https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-automatic-silent-adobe-flash-updates/

When installing Adobe Flash using the exe installer, you will be prompted to select your update preference. If you use the “Allow Adobe to install updates” option, the Flash updates will install automatically.

[image]

If you go to the Task Scheduler, you can see that there is a new Adobe Flash Player Updater task that is scheduled to run daily. The task runs with System privileges. That means that even users without Administrator rights can have Flash updates installed silently without receiving prompts or requiring IT assistance.

[image]

If you selected “Notify me to install updates” for “Never check for updates,” you can go to the Control Panel and access the Flash Player Settings Manager. Click the Change Update Settings button, approve the User Account Control (UAC) prompt, and change the setting to “Allow Adobe to install updates.”

[image]

**Hope That Helps!**

Comment: hello, I noticed that when downloading flash for Firefox it prompts for also donwloading yahoo toolbar and some intel bloatware. By allowing Adobe to auto instaling updates will also auto install 3rd parties software?

Comment: @S.Redrum - no, I don't believe so. But take a look at your program manager before and after install to be certain. If it installs anything unwanted, simply uninstall it.

Comment: Accordingly to [Adobe support](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2364468) it will not, thank you!

Comment: How do you resume the Flash Player Settings Manager from the Task Scheduler?